# C# Storing User specific data .NET3.5

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, .net-3.5

im currently on a Windows Forms Application with target framework .Net 3.5

Im looking for a simple way to store user specific data, like a username or a department id. 
All google finds dont seems to work or is for another Framework.

Every Windows user should access its own settings at any PC in our shop.
There is a mountet user specific partition where i could store and read some files but whats the best way to do so ?

I want at least something simple like:

```
UserSettings.Instance.SetValue(SettingsKey.Username, "AwesomeUser");
String username = UserSettings.Instance.GetValue(SettingsKey.Username);
```

to access the data.

Any Hints ?

Comment: Ever heard of [Active Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742424.aspx)?

Comment: Active directory or creating your own user management system with a SQL server backend such as asp.net identity: https://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: There is already a user specific directory, and I'm very restricted because it's a company network.

Comment: You can do this many different ways.  The two ways that are probably easiest are to use an instance of SQL Server Express (free, comes with Visual Studio, can deploy with the app) and put the users, settings, etc. into tables.  That's the "what Brian Boitano'd do" approach.   Alternatively you can just write this to a plaintext, XML, or CSV file local to the machine.

Comment: Then you may use a xml/json file per user, if that directory is accesible from every pc.Anyway, if it is a corporate network, i would ask if AD is present

Comment: @Pikoh is there a good json or xml parser arrond ?

Comment: There are parsers for both [JSON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770(v=vs.110).aspx) and [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bcctyt8(v=vs.110).aspx) built into .NET.

Comment: I have a little access database where the application data is stored but I didn't want to store user data in it.

Comment: I hoped there were a simpler way, like NSUserDefaults from apples Foundation